# Product get out of stock after order on Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a really weird behavior on Woocommerce with the stock management. On a product with stock management enabled, a stock of 100 items and stock status "available", every time I do an order the product stock go to negative and get out of stock.

For example, if I do an order of 2 items of the product, the stock go to -2 right after the order, even if the stock was at 100 right before.

The product is a simple one, without any attribute. I use the following hooks to alter some label and stuffs, but none seems related to this issue:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', array(&$this->wc, 'add_to_cart_text'), 11);
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart', array(&$this->wc, 'add_to_cart'), 10, 1);
add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_removed', array(&$this->wc, 'cart_item_removed'), 10, 1);
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', array(&$this->wc, 'order_status_completed'), 10, 1);
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', array(&$this->wc, 'replace_add_to_cart'));
```

In short, `woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text` change the add to cart button label, `woocommerce_add_to_cart` place some vars in session, `woocommerce_cart_item_removed` remove those session var on item removal from cart, `woocommerce_order_status_completed` do some stuffs with the session vars (update a CPT from those session vars - I don't touch the order or the product at all) and `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` display a button on product listing. I tried to disable the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook, it didn't change anything.

I will paste any code of those function if any of you think some could be related to this stock issue.

I'm using latest version of Woocommerce and Wordpress.

Comment: I don't have an immediate answer, but I would test with all your custom code removed, with all plugins disabled, and with a default theme. Then slowly re-enable all the pieces until you can isolate the culprit. If the problem persists in a default state we can assume a bug in WooCommerce and should report it at their [github](http://www.github.com/woothemes/woocommerce).

Comment: @helgatheviking You were right, some plugin provided by the theme (Shindig) was doing this. I posted an answer explaining this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the culprit, as helgatheviking suggested I disabled all the plugins one by one and found out that the plugin **Progression One Click Import** provided by [the theme](http://themeforest.net/item/shindig-a-rocking-single-event-theme/11200961) and marked as "recommended for theme use" was doing this.

My guess is that it is related to this filter in the plugin code:

```
add_filter( 'add_post_metadata', array( $this, 'check_previous_meta' ), 10, 5 );
```

Which is doing this:

```
public function check_previous_meta( $continue, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ) {
    $old_value = get_metadata( 'post', $post_id, $meta_key );
    if ( count( $old_value ) == 1 ) {
        if ( $old_value[0] === $meta_value ) {
            return false;
        } elseif ( $old_value[0] !== $meta_value ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The flaw in this is that it is inserting the stock meta value raw (-2) instead of decrementing the existing meta value, which Woocommerce seems to do with some filter on his end - a behavior that is overwrited by this filter.

I guess this could be fixed by changing the filter priority but just disabling the plugin was good for me as I don't need to import preview data.